Updating BoxCollider parameters in animation tab (Dopesheet)
I tried to change the values of the center and size of the BoxCollider (3d) throughout the animation.
I have encountered a problem that any entered BoxCollider values were immediately reset to the current ones. (my changes does not apply for some reason).
This problem occurs only with the BoxCollider parameter. Animator or Transform parameters changes properly.
The collider and animator components are located in the same root GameObject.

Doesn't Unity support changing the box collider in DropSheet, or is there something else going on here?
UPD:
Ok, I think I found a clue:
Colliders values are changing if they are placed in a Child object with an animator as well. Still have no idea why its fails in root object...
